# Certain games cause screen to freeze and go black for a second

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, freeze, nvidia-graphics-card

On occasions when playing certain video games (through steam) the screen will freeze briefly, turn black and then recover and resume gameplay as normal, not even 2 minutes into gameplay. I run far-more graphic intensive games (eg. Skyrim + mods/ENB & Wolfenstein: New Order in comparison to Orcs Must Die 2) without any issue whatsoever for much longer periods of time, so what could this indicate?

I've tried clean installing and updating my nVidia drivers and even checking if there was a new Direct X out, even trying to disable things like V-Sync and AA through Nvidia control panel/game settings but neither of these were the answer to my problem.

Here are my system specs:

[image]

Comment: The problem you describe indicates the display driver is crashing. Not all demanding games are created equal.  If one uses DirectX and the other is OpenGL that could explain why one works adn the other does not.

Comment: I see, I currently have the Nvidia beta drivers installed, I'll try going to the stable drivers now.